# Flutter push to a new page with a transition effect that cause the previous page keep pushing behind

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

May i know what is this effect call? Is there a plugin can achieve something like this in flutter pub dev or do we need to do some customisation on our page route builder? Thank you.

[image]